# Maximizing Mutual information of a Fading Channel with Additive Gaussian Noise

Tags: information-theory, entropy, mutual-information

I am considering a problem such that we have a channel $Y=XV+Z$. Assuming $X,V,Z$ all independent

Where $$Z \sim \mathcal{N}(0, N)$$

and
$$
V=\begin{cases}
\alpha_1, & p\\
\alpha_2, & (1-p)
\end{cases}
$$

With Power Constraint $E[X^2] \le P$

Here is the approach I have used to attempt to maxmize the mutual information:

\begin{align}
I(X;Y) &= h(Y) - h(Y|X)\\
&= h(Y)- h(XV+Z|X)\\
&\le h(Y) - h(XV+Z|X,V)\\
&=h(Y) - p \ h(\alpha_1X+Z|X,V=\alpha_1) - (1-p)\ h(\alpha_2X+Z|X,V=\alpha_2)\\
&= h(Y) - p\ h(Z) - (1-p)\ h(Z)\\
&= h(Y) - h(Z)
\end{align}

Then $h(Y)$ is maximized for $Y$ gaussian.

\begin{align}
Var(Y) &= Var(XV+Z)\\
&= Var(XV) + Var(Z)\\
&\le \sqrt{Var(X)Var(V)} + E[Z^2] &(\text{Cauchy-Shwarz})\\
&\le \sqrt{PVar(V)} +N
\end{align}

Then my upper bound on the mutual information is

\begin{align}
I(X;Y) \le \frac{1}{2}log\bigg(1+ \frac{\sqrt{PVar(V)}}{N}\bigg)
\end{align}

which I suppose is maximized when $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0,P)$.

Question: Is this the right approach to take to find the maximum?

Typically, I have seen fading channels with deterministic multiplication factors, so I wanted to consider a problem where the multiplicative factor is a random variable.

Answer (score 2):

extended comment.

Your attempt has the following issues:

1. the application of the Cauchy inequality is wrong.
2. $Y$ cannot be Gaussian even with $X$ Gaussian (it is a mixture
   of Gaussians in that case).
3. (Most important one) Are you sure conditioning the entropy of an arbitrary distributed real-valued random variable reduces its entropy in this case? "Conditioning reduces entropy" holds for discrete-valued
   variables, but not always for real-valued variables. The way you
   employ this inequality suggests you have made some assumption
   about $X$ distribution (such that the inequality indeed holds). But,
   doing so, you are effectively restricting yourself to a specific $X$
   distribution and you cannot claim you are computing a universal upper bound.
   You are only computing an upper bound for that specific $X$
   distribution.